# Design by Contract: Can we express Stack FILO property with contract?

Tags: oop, code-contracts, design-by-contract

It seems that design by contract has limit to express specification. For example, i tried to express Stack FILO property with contract, but didn't get an idea. Anybody can help?

I think the root cause is that precondition/postcondition/invariant are assertations without side effects. It leads to the checking of FILO property which is a kind of side effects not easy even possible.

Answer (score 2):

That's true, design by contract has limited functionality. They are not panacea. Because if they were then the IT industry would throw out unit-testing, code reviews etc.

I suggest you to write simple unit-test for this case rather than crack your head by implementing a contract (which even may be unimplementable).

Comment: The "because if they were ..." reasoning seems like a good explanation of why we're still all riding horses when we want to go places. Oh, wait, we aren't.

Comment: I keep forgetting that sarcasm is frowned upon on StackOverflow, so here is the non-sarcastic version: you are invoking the "if it was really better everyone would already be doing it" argument for a feature that was first made available in Visual Studio 2010. We are in 2010. There are plenty of valid reasons why code contracts may be unsatisfactory. The meta-reasoning invoked in your answer is not one.

Comment: "The term was coined by Bertrand Meyer in connection with his design of the Eiffel programming language and first described in various articles starting in 1986[2][3][4] and the two successive editions (1988, 1997) of his book Object-Oriented Software Construction."

Comment: I infered from the "code-contracts" tag that the question was in the context of VS2010. Actually the question does not make this very clear. If we are talking about Design by Contract in general, there are plenty of possibilities for the language in which to express pre/post-conditions, some of which do not limit in practice what you can express.

Comment: What? There ARE ways to write contracts with side-effects?